# Character limit when generating an email?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using the code below to generate an email and if the complaint textbox is greater than 30-40 characters the email does not generate and I just get a blank IE page. Is there some sort of limit?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function sendMail(CustomerTextbox, AddressTextBox, CityTextBox, StateDropDown, ZipTextBox, ModelTextbox, SerialTextbox, ReferenceTextbox, ComplaintTextBox, WarrentyTextBox) {
   var CustomerTextbox = document.getElementById(CustomerTextbox).value;
   var AddressTextBox = document.getElementById(AddressTextBox).value;
   var CityTextBox = document.getElementById(CityTextBox).value;
   var StateDropDown = document.getElementById(StateDropDown).value;
   var ZipTextBox = document.getElementById(ZipTextBox).value;
   var ModelTextbox = document.getElementById(ModelTextbox).value;
   var SerialTextbox = document.getElementById(SerialTextbox).value;
   var ReferenceTextbox = document.getElementById(ReferenceTextbox).value;
   var ComplaintTextBox = document.getElementById(ComplaintTextBox).value;
   var WarrentyTextBox = document.getElementById(WarrentyTextBox).value;

   var body = "Please issue a RMA for this case." + "\r\n";
   body += CustomerTextbox + "\r\n";
   body += AddressTextBox + "\r\n";
   body += CityTextBox + "\r\n";
   body += StateDropDown + "\r\n";
   body += ZipTextBox + "\r\n";
   body += ModelTextbox + "\r\n";
   body += SerialTextbox + "\r\n";
   body += ReferenceTextbox + "\r\n";
   body += ComplaintTextBox + "\r\n";
   body += WarrentyTextBox + "\r\n";

   document.location = "mailto:&subject=" + "Name - " + CustomerTextbox + "&body=" + escape(body);
```

}

Comment: Can u show the rest of the function? What is happening with `body`?

Comment: What is the final value of `body`?

Comment: I posted the rest sorry

Comment: In general you can't rely on the client's mail agent paying any attention to your "body" parameter at all.

Comment: How many total characters is the entire body?  There is a limit on a URL (differs per browser) which may be what you are running into.

Comment: Ya but for some reason it works most of the time but some reason I think theres a character limit

Comment: So the sendmail function I am using is going through IE? And thats why I have a limit issue?

Comment: You're not using any sendmail, as described your function launches your local email client (outlook etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer has a maximum URL length of 2,083 characters,
[see Microsoft Support KB 208427](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427).

Also check out [question 417142](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers).